# Opa: How to Manually Invalidate a Cached Value

Tags: opa

### The Setup

I'm trying to implement a fairly common caching pattern. Here's what I want to happen:

1. The first time a record is requested, its value is cached.
2. Subsequent requests return the cached record.
3. When a record is changed, the cached version is marked invalid.
4. The next request for the record caches a new value.

### The Problem

`Cache.simple()` caches values as expected, but I don't seem to have a tool for invalidating a cached value. `Cache.make()` seems to be the tool intended for this job, but I've failed to successfully employ it.

### The Source

This is a complete example (that builds and runs). I want to invalidate the cached record at the end of `set_name` (after storing a new value). If the cached record is successfully invalidated, a name submitted from the text input should be displayed when the page has refreshed.

```
type User.t = 
  { id : int 
  ; name : string
  }

db /user: intmap(User.t)

create_user() =
  match ?/user[0] with
  | {none} -> /user[0] <- {id=0 name="tom"}
  | _ -> void

set_name(new_name: string) =
  /user[0]/name <- new_name
  // After setting a new name, invalidate the cached result.

_get_name(uid:int) : string =
  /user[uid]/name
get_name = Cache.simple(_get_name)

page() =
  do create_user()
  <>User's name is "{get_name(0)}"</>

  <form onsubmit={_ -> set_name(Dom.get_value(#name_input))}>
    <input type="text" id=#name_input />
  </form>

server = one_page_server("User", page)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `Cache.make` is the way to go if you want more control, i.e. in this case invalidate the results. What problem did you have?

You need to start with creating a cache over your `_get_name` function. For that you can mimic `Cache.simple`:

```
get_name = Cache.make(Cache.Negotiator.always_necessary(_get_name), Cache.default_options)
```

then instead of `get_name` use `get_name.get` (`get_name` is the cache) and in your `create_user` function use `get_name.invalidate(0)` to invalidate the cached result.

Does that help?

Comment: This is exactly the example I needed. Thanks.